# Get "recent files" in global file manager (Dolphin?)

Tags: files, kde, defaults, gimp, dolphin

I just switched to OpenSUSE (KDE) from my Fedora 20 KDE setup,and I find myself greatly missing a feature that was a default in Fedora: a "Recently Used" option in the file manager when saving and uploading files. As far as I can tell, both are using Dolphin, but the appearance is inconsistent. I still see something like what I want in Gimp (see the "recently used"):
[image: gimp manager shows "Recent"]

But every other file manager looks like this (notice the impoverished left-side menu):

[image]

I've set Dolphin as my default everywhere I can see to go (such as "Configure Desktop" -> "Default Applications" -> "File Manager") but I can't get an appearance that matches the Gimp one (at least in the Places menu). I want the menu back because it saves tons of time on uploads and downloads online, and as a web professional, it's a big deal for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add this entry manually: right click on the Places, choose Add Entry, enter this in Location field: `recentdocuments:///` and save it. It should be available now in all KDE/Qt file dialogs.

Comment: Brilliant! Is this a Nepomuk function? Where is the documentation for this and similar things?

Comment: https://docs.kde.org/stable4/en/applications/dolphin/location-bar.html#location-bar-editable-kioslaves

Comment: This isn't working on plasmashell 5.13.5, but `recent:` works.